# matrix array plotting opposite of what i want matplotlib

Tags: python, matrix, matplotlib

I have created a matrix

```
arr_n = np.ones((N,N), dtype = 'bool')
arr_n[arr_d[:,1], arr_d[:,0]] = 0
arr_d = np.array(data)       
self.ax.imshow(arr_n, cmap=plt.cm.spectral_r)
```

I have chosen `spectral_r` as afterwards I want to add color to the points. I have come across a problem however. Instead of plotting the data I want(in black) it plots the things that I do not want instead. So I am left with the opposite of what I want. i.e the data i want plotting is white and the part I don't has been plotted(in black).
`data = [(14,64),(23,45),(12,34)]`

Comment: `spectral` is the reverse color scheme of `spectral_r`. Does that help?

Comment: Thanks, your question was helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the inverse of the colormap:

```
self.ax.imshow(arr_n, cmap=plt.cm.spectral)
```

Or plot the inverse of your boolean matrix.

```
self.ax.imshow(np.invert(arr_n), cmap=plt.cm.spectral)
```